# Docker Container Mount Volume to Hosts Mounted Network Share

Tags: docker

I have a Docker host that has a mounter network share to a folder on the host /mnt/share/folder the share works just fine. I need to be able to mount this share on the host to the container. I tried `-v /mnt/share/folder:/folder` and when I start the container it tells me that I cannot write to the location.

Basically, the share has files that I want to be able to read/write from the container. I need the container to be able to create files/folders to the share.

I have also tried `--mount type=bind,source=/mnt/share/folder,target=/folder` and Docker will not build the it.

Comment: I have been working on a like issue, using a cifs-mounted network share on the host, and even if I get it to set the permissions, I am always unable to write to the drive. I have yet to test installing cifs-utils on the container, but I expect this functionality simply is not available (yet), and yes I also tried the suggestions found here and all over. Let you know if I do get it...

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend mounting the share to the container using the docker nfs volume plugin directly

```
$ docker volume create --driver local \
--opt type=nfs \
--opt o=addr=192.168.1.1,rw \
--opt device=:/path/to/dir \
foo
```

Comment: `--driver local` doesn't seem to be recognized as a flag

Comment: idk why the downvote, it's a standard option, see https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_create/